# Exchange Web Service - Sending email without tenant admin consent?

Tags: azure, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to send an email through EWS, following the instructions here:
[Authenticate an EWS application by using OAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth). I want to configure for delegated authentication, have registered my app on Azure, with API permission 'EWS.AccessAsUser.All' been added.

[App registration page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnxN5.png)

On the Azure Web UI, it tells me no admin consent is needed, but when I run the example code in above tutorial, got an exception at line:

```
var authResult = await pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync();
```

a login window pop out, and after I enter user name and password, it says 'Need admin approval - (MyAppName) needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it.'

[Popup window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9HJQ.png)

Do I have to get admin's consent for this? Is the Azure UI info conflict with what the popup have said?

Thanks!

Comment: It requires either User or Admin consent however depending on how user consent is configured in your org https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent?tabs=azure-portal the portal doesn't take this into account so while the user can consent to the permission its not applicable due to the tenant config.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Sounds that's the case, I'll recheck it with my tenant admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [Glen Scales](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1080923/glen-scales).  Adding your comment as answer to help other community users.

Either User or Admin consent is required, however depending on how user consent is [configured in your org](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent?tabs=azure-portal), the portal doesn't take this into account. So while the user can consent to the permission, its not applicable due to the tenant config